# C - Why are my int values extremely large?

Tags: c, integer

I am going to try and give enough information in snippets of code, as most of it is irrelevant to the question.  Please let me know if you need more code.

I am trying to read from a txt file using fscanf in order to make a matrix.  The format of the file is as follows:

(integer declaring number of rows)

(integer declaring number of columns)

(value1, value2, ......, value n)

.

.

(last row values)

I use the following code (trimmed of irrelevancies) to obtain the number of rows and columns in the matrix:

```
FILE* fp;
int row,col;    

row = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));
col = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));

fp = fopen(fname, "r");
fscanf(fp, "%d %d", row, col);
printf("%d %d \n", row, col);
```

The values that are printed out have varied, but always been very large, i.e. "5977072 5977088," or "4797424 4797440."  I'm rather new to C and would love to know why this is happening.  My two hypotheses are as follows:

1. The memory which is allocated for the values contained these large numbers to begin with, and for some reason row and col are not being set to the values in the matrix txt file.
2. What is being printed are the addresses for row and col.

If it is the case of scenario 1, then what am I doing wrong in setting the values of row and col?  Is there some point at which I am supposed to manipulate pointers?

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: Why are you allocating memory from the heap for `row` and `col`?

Comment: Because my program was crashing otherwise.  When it would try to scan I believe it didn't have anywhere to place the values so it would crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You failed to declare `row` and `col` as pointers to integers...

Your declaration should look like

```
int *row, *col;
```

Because of this, you are just generating random garbage data.

**Update**: *pointers* are a critical aspect of C.  The simplest definition of a *pointer* is that it *points* to a region of memory.

When you use `malloc(n)`, it finds an uninterrupted region of unused memory that is `n` bytes large.  So because you used `malloc`, you have to store the result in a pointer.

Pointers are also useful for returning multiple values, a function such as `scanf` can be passed pointers to the regions of memory that the user wants to be filled with the return values.  This is why you use `scanf` like this:

```
int row, col;
scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
```

Or alternatively, you can allocate on the heap as you did in your question:

```
int *row = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *col = malloc(sizeof(int));
scanf("%d %d", row, col);
```

Both ways are perfectly legal.  Although, for a data type such as `int` which happens to be smaller than `int *` (on most systems, on others it can be the same size), the latter one is frowned upon.

Comment: Is there some reading you can point me to that can help me understand this better?  I honestly just don't know when I should be declaring as pointers.

Comment: @ChristianBaker See my update for a small guide on the uses of pointers.  For more advanced usage, the best place to learn is by looking at the header files for major libraries like zlib.